# How to signing Android APK

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have create an Android application with Cordova platform using Netbeans. 
The application runs on Android emulator.

To build this application, I add **<application android:debuggable="false" [...] />** in AndroidManifest.xml. I uploaded into google play and I found failed message like "Upload APK signed in debug mode. You need to signing the APK in release mode."

And I found this RSA public key too in my google play panel;

```
YOUR LICENSE KEY FOR THIS APPLICATION Base64-encoded RSA public key to include in your binary. Please remove any spaces.
MIIBIjANBgasdfasdfdaskqhkiG9w0BAQEadfadfasdFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuacIf........
```

Would you please tell me how to use the RSA key? And please, tell me the easy way (not using eclipse) because I am new to Android development. If you don't mine, please tell me step by step to signing it because I have try to solve this problem for a day :(

Comment: Why don't you want to use Eclipse ? Use Eclipse and your problem would be easier to solve.

Comment: I have been trying to use Eclipse too. It make me more confuse. I don't know what is workspace. And when I create workspace and get into Eclipse, now what should I do? Create project again? create new project with existing folder? Where is my Android project which I have done in Netbeans (What should I do with this)? Oh dear... I told you, I am very new to this. A little rude to say... I am stupid to this. And, this is 2nd day to me to solve this without result. Thank for down vote

Comment: I see no point in using eclipse when using cordova. In cordova you do js/html 99% of the time and eclipse is really not the best editor for webapps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how netbeans installs cordova, but you should have access to the cli (command line interface).

With the cli here is how to sign the app :

First modify AndroidManifest.xml to set android:debuggable to false like you did and also change android:versionCode if you already released a version of your app.

then run `cordova build android --release` to generate an unsigned release version of the app. It will create a file named yourappname-release-unsigned.apk in the platforms/android/ant-build folder of your project (..../bin before cordova 3.4).

Now sign your app, you need to have already created a keystore :

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore yourkeystore.keystore yourappname-release-unsigned.apk youraliasforthekeystore
```

And finally, you align the app :

```
zipalign -v 4 yourappname-release-unsigned.apk yourappname-release-signed.apk
```

Now you should be able to submit yourappname-release-signed.apk to google play