# Publishing / releasing android app using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I'am trying to build the final release version of my app that using phonegap 3.0 and a few plugins. I have followed [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316910/phonegap-run-from-cli-with-release-and-self-signed-app-requires-me-to-patch-co) to link my keystore file to the app however I am not sure this is working.

Everything runs locally when I use `phonegap run android`.

Into `myapp/platforms/android` I have placed `ant.properties`

```
key.store=/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/keystore/my-release-key.keystore

key.alias=FishAppKey      //I wasn't sure as it is suggested this can be whatever.
```

When I build my app instead of placing the .apk files into `platforms/android/bin` they are put into  `platforms/android/ant-build`?

When I move into `platforms/android` and run `ant release` I get Build failed ...tools/ant/build.xml:698:null returned 1

Really I am trying to figure out how to go from `phonegap run android` to a apk file I can upload to google play.

Comment: Have you tried the online build? You can upload your keystore there and it will build with the key...

Comment: @Renanlf Hi I was under the impression because I am using an admob plugin I have to build it locally? If I use phonegap build the plugins do not work...

Comment: 1) it's in ant-build instead of bin since version 3.4 of cordova/phonegap. 2) check my answer in this other post, maybe it'll help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034823/how-to-signing-android-apk/23057835#23057835

Comment: @QuickFix Thanks, I am just at the point of signing my app. My keystore file is located on my desktop. Could you elaborate on the sign your app step. Do I need to move the keystore somewhere? etc Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answer to your comment, you use jarsigner and pass the full path to your keystore in the -keystore argument. So let's say your keystore is on the desktop and named yourkeystore.keystore,

- On Windows you would :

`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore %userprofile%\Desktop\yourkeystore.keystore yourappname-release-unsigned.apk youraliasforthekeystore`

- On linux (and probably OSX also):

`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $HOME/Desktop/yourkeystore.keystore yourappname-release-unsigned.apk youraliasforthekeystore`

And of course you can replace yourappname-release-unsigned.apk with the full path of your apk in case it's not in the current directory.